# How to pass variable through ChannelExec.setCommand() method in JSch in Java?

Tags: java, session, ssh, jsch

Below is my code. Please check

```
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
channelExec.setCommand("sh "+ "a.sh; echo \\$No");
```

`a.sh` is my shell script in Linux server. I need to run the script along with value of `No` (received as a parameter of a Java function).

However, the value of the No is not  getting passed over to my shell script.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a regular Java string, what you are passing to the `ChannelExec.setCommand()`. So use string concatenation (as you are doing already):

```
channelExec.setCommand("sh "+ "a.sh; echo \\" + No);
```